# Difference between android:layout_property and android:property

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am new to Android Application Development.

I was wondering what is the difference between specifying `android:layout_someproperty` and `android:someproperty`. For example `android:layout_height` and `android:height`.

My Eclipse on hover provides the following information

```
android:layout_height : Specifies the basic height of the view.[dimension.enum]
android:height : Makes the TextView exactly this many pixel tall[dimention]
```

But I don't get it. My code is something like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainscreen_background"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TicTacToe" >

    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/game_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24.5sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What makes sense and what effect does each have?

1. setting `android:layout_height` in `LinerLayout` tag.
2. setting `android:layout_height` in `TextView` tag.
3. setting `android:height` in `LinerLayout` tag.
4. setting `android:height` in `TextView` tag.

As far as my understanding goes `LinearLayout` would be the parent of `TextView`(Correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

well, setting layout_height is actually not a property of the View, but its sourrounding Layout. android:height, sets the Views height.

In general you use the layout_height and try to avoid any kind of absolute value, since that would look weird on screens with different aspect ratio/size

You have to set android:layout_height on both, textview and LinearLayout.

if this is your whole fragment, i would set the root view to match_parent in both dimensions, and usually you set the child view layout_height to wrap content and layout_width to match parent.

This will create a textview that occupies the whole width of his parent, and adapt to the size of its content.